# Setting only before request logs CommonsRequestLoggingFilter in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging

`CommonsRequestLoggingFilter` is quite good in logging requests but in my case, it is logging the same thing before and after the request is processed, which is duplicate and redundant. I want to get rid of the after request processing logs but I couldn't find how to do it. Any ideas?

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter;

@Configuration
public class RequestLoggingFilterConfig {

    @Bean
    public CommonsRequestLoggingFilter logFilter() {
        CommonsRequestLoggingFilter filter = new CommonsRequestLoggingFilter();
        filter.setIncludeClientInfo(true);
        filter.setIncludeHeaders(true);
        filter.setIncludePayload(false);
        filter.setIncludeQueryString(true);
        return filter;
    }
}
```

I started off from [here.](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-http-logging)

Comment: Have you find any solution ?

Comment: @Junaid No I wasn't able to find any solution at the time being. When I asked this question there were no answers at all so I added customized logs for each endpoint. That's why I wasn't able to try the answer below. I'm sorry but it was kinda late for me.

Comment: I also asked this question to Baeldung team and they forwarded me to the this url: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-handlerinterceptor Maybe it can be helpful for you. @Junaid

Comment: Thanks @Ieventunver for the link, I will surely take a look.

Answer (score 9):

The class [org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/web/filter/CommonsRequestLoggingFilter.html) is just a subclass of [org.springframework.web.filter.AbstractRequestLoggingFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.html). Thus skip CommonsRequestLoggingFilter and write your own subclass and leave the overwritten method `afterRequest()` empty.

```
public class CustomizedRequestLoggingFilter extends AbstractRequestLoggingFilter {

    @Override
    protected void beforeRequest(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, String message) {
        this.logger.debug(message);
    }

    @Override
    protected void afterRequest(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, String message) {

    }
}
```

Use this class instead of [org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/web/filter/CommonsRequestLoggingFilter.html)

Answer (score 5):

To avoid the duplicate logging, when instantiating the `CommonsRequestLoggingFilter` you have to override either of the two:

- beforeRequest()
- afterRequest()

To disable the logging in afterRequest(), the OP's code can be changed as follows:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter;

@Configuration
public class RequestLoggingFilterConfig {

    @Bean
    public CommonsRequestLoggingFilter logFilter() {
        CommonsRequestLoggingFilter filter = new CommonsRequestLoggingFilter() {
            @Override
            public void afterRequest(HttpServletRequest request, String message) {
                // No body, we are just overriding the default behavior
            }
        };

        filter.setIncludeClientInfo(true);
        filter.setIncludeHeaders(true);
        filter.setIncludePayload(false);
        filter.setIncludeQueryString(true);
        return filter;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that in this case (extending using an anonymous class), the log level needs to be set on the config class itself, E.g.  `logging.level.com.mypackage.myproject.RequestLoggingFilterConfig=DEBUG`